# Nice upper bound on $max{|x|, |y|}$ in terms of $d$ in Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

Given Pell's equation $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$, can we come up with a nice upper bound on $max(|x|,|y|)$ in terms of $d$? Also, if it's somehow more tractable, are we able to find an upper bound on $|x+y|$? Assume that we have a non-trivial solution $(x,y)$.

I've done a bit of cursory research and haven't found any official result like this. Reference to a result  or perhaps some insight into the question would be valuable. This inquiry arose in my head while learning about continued fraction expansions and things of that sort in number theory.

I did see [Pell equations upper bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611411/pell-equations-upper-bound), but it doesn't quite get at my question. Or, at the very least, I am curious to learn more.

Comment: I believe you know how to compute the general solution in terms of a particular solution? I believe all you have to do is maximize over $n$ in that solution, and you can clearly see that the solutions would be unbounded.

Comment: Kaind raises a good point.  Do you actually mean an upper bound on $|x+y|$ or an upper bound for the *smallest* non-trivial solution?  If the latter, your question doesn't state this, so you should clarify this (and it would make the question more interesting).

Comment: If $(x_1, y_1)$ is any solution, and $k$ is any positive integer, then $(X_k, Y_k)$ is also a solution, where $(X_k + Y_k\sqrt{D}~) = (x_1 + y_1\sqrt{D}~)^k.$  Clearly, the sequences $\{X_1, X_2, \cdots \}$ and $\{Y_1, Y_2, \cdots \}$ are both increasing without bound.

Comment: Note that *conjugation* is multiplicative, so $(X_k - Y_k\sqrt{D}~) = (x_1 - y_1\sqrt{D}~)^k$.  Therefore, $$1 = ([x_1]^2 - D[y_1]^2)^k = (x_1 + y_1 \sqrt{D}~)^k (x_1 - y_1\sqrt{D}~)^k = (X_k + Y_k\sqrt{D}~)(X_k - Y_k\sqrt{D}~) = ([X_k]^2 - D[Y_k]^2).$$

Comment: For Pell Equation sources, I recommend chapter 1 of [pdf-1](http://bit.ly/pdf-khinchin)
and, as a supplement, [pdf-2](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).  When
I examined pdf-1, I wasn't interested in the material after chapter 1.  Although
pdf-2 will seem basic, I still found it to be valuable.